# How can i iterate to find all the firsts quotes and the lasts quotes to replace?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to replace all the first and last quotes in a string, i tried to do with 'while' and 'for', but i can't reach success.

How can i do this?

Input: This is a input: Text "example" to show "the" expected output

Output: This is a input: Text ''example´´ to show ''the´´ expected output

To be clear, the first quote of the pair needs to be replaced by 2 apostrophes and the second needs to be replaced by 2 Sharp accents

This is the code that replaces only 2 occurrences in a string, it's working, but it's not complete.

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input: ");
        string str =  " \"aspas\" e mais \"aspas\" "/*Console.ReadLine()*/;
        str = SubstituiPrimeiro(str, "\"", "''");
        str = SubstituiUltimo(str, "\"", "´´");

        Console.WriteLine("Output: {0}", str);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Replace first
    public static string SubstituiPrimeiro(string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pre = text.IndexOf(search);

        if (pre < 0)
            return text;
        return text.Substring(0, pre) + replace + text.Substring(pre + search.Length);
    }

    //Replace last
    public static string SubstituiUltimo(string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
        if (pos < 0)
            return text;
        return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    }
}
```

**I tried to do the following (and with 'for' also):**

```
//Replace first
public static string SubstituiPrimeiro(string text, string search, string replace)
{
    int pre = text.IndexOf(search);

    while (pre < 0)
        return text;

    return text.Substring(0, pre) + replace + text.Substring(pre + search.Length);
}
```

Comment: you are trying to replace ALL quotes??

Comment: All the quotes, or just the matched pairs?

Comment: Did you try the replace method https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx if you are trying to replace the quotes

Comment: yes, but in this way it's not distinguished the firsts and the lasts

Comment: for and while doesn't make any difference here @KaioMartins

Comment: What do you mean by first and last?

Comment: Provide sample input and your expected result to make the question more clear

Comment: It's just the matched pairs

Comment: Since the question is not clear no one will be able provide the answer unless you specify the input and output

Comment: Input: This is a input Text "example" to show "the" expected output.

Output: This is a input Text ''example´´ to show ''the´´ expected output.

To be clear, the first quote of the pair needs to be replaced by 2 apostrophes and the second needs to be replaced by 2 Sharp accents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach

```
string text = "Example \"text\" of my own \"only\" to show the expexted";
int minIndex = text.IndexOf('"');
int count = 1;
while (minIndex != -1)
{
    text = text.Insert(minIndex + 1, count % 2 == 0 ? "´´" : "''").Remove(minIndex, 1);
    count++;
    minIndex = text.IndexOf('"', minIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use String.LastIndexOf in SubstituiUltimo method.

Comment: in this way if there's more than 1 pair of quotes, only the first and last of the string are changed. like this:

This is a input Text ''example" to show "the´´ expected output